# Grab any string starting with http up until first whitespace character in php

Tags: php, regex

I am having problems grabbing some text using preg_replace() in php. I am just trying to remove all text that starts with a http|https|www up until the first whitespace character. I am currently using:
    (http|https|www)\S+
as my regex in preg_replace(). However I am getting this error when running the code:
    Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '\'
I can use this same regex in a text editor, e.g. Sublime Text 2 with no problem. Any ideas why I am getting this error? Is there another way to grab the text I am looking for with a regex?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must delimit your regular expressions. This is usually a slash (`/`), but can also be a pair of parentheses. After the second delimiter can follow a number of delimiters (multi-line regex, ignore white-space, case-insensitive, etc.). `\` is not a valid modifier, and thus, PHP complains.

Modify your regex as follows:

```
preg_replace('/(http|https|www)\S+/', …, …);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware that you had to delimit the regex in slashes. Fixed my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$string = preg_replace( '%(http|https|www).*?\s%', '', $string );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a ^ infront of your regexp:

```
/^(http|http|www)/
```

This matches only at the beginning of the string

Answer (score 0):

**This one works :** [ demo : http://regexr.com?30l4d ]

```
$newstring = preg_replace( "/((https?|www).*?)\s/", "", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful about how strings are escaped with php:

For instance, `"\s"` is an escaped s, and `'\s'` is a backash folowed by a s.

Also don't forget to add slashes at the begining and the end of your regexp. For example: `'/myregexp.*/'`